# What cannot be calculated using density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Let's say I have a compound quantum system (CQS) in an (unknown to me) pure state $\left|\Psi\right>$. If an operator $\mathbf{A}$ acts only on variables of a subsystem (S) of CQS, then I can calculate expectation value of the corresponding observable as

$$
    \bar{A} = \textrm{Tr} (\mathbf{\rho}_S \mathbf{A})
$$

where $\mathbf{\rho}_S$ is a partial density matrix of S (trace over other subsystems of CQS). I can do this for any observable (that acts only on S).

So, *if I limit myself to S* what is it that I cannot calculate using $\mathbf{\rho}_S$ that I'd be able to calculate if I knew $\left|\Psi\right>$? It seems such things should exist, otherwise I'd be able to construct the wave function for S (is that correct?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I explain how one would reconstruct a "wavefunction" from a density matrix known to come from a pure state. However, your situation is different. If $\rho$ is the density matrix of an entangled pure state of two systemsn $S$ and $S'$, then $\rho_S$ is the density matrix of a *mixed state* of $S$, see also [this question and its answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167159/50583). A mixed state does not have a unique wavefunction, so the question of whether you can reconstruct the wavefunction is meaningless. By design, if you are only interested in observables of $S$, then $\rho_S$ contains all necessary information for that - the partial trace is the reverse of the operation of "combining" quantum systems, and if you apply it to a non-entangled state of the combined system it just gives back the corresponding pure state of $S$, which obviously contains all necessary information about $S$.

---

You *are* able to construct the wave-function for a density matrix $\rho$ if you know that it comes from a pure state that has such a wavefunction. Or at least, you are able to construct the only physically meaningful content of the wavefunction:

You can compute how likely it is that the system is in a region $R\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ by computing the expectation value of the associated spectral projector $P_R$ (which acts on wavefunctions by multiplying them with the characteristic function of $R$; in non-rigorous language you may think of this as the operator that projects onto the space spanned by position eigenstates with eigenvalues in $R$), and this is what the wavefunction is - a probability density that tells you how likely it is the system is in a region $R$ by integrating the wavefunction over it. The values of the wavefunction at single points are physically irrelevant and therefore you should not expect to be able to recover them - the wavefunction is formally a representant of an equivalence class of square-integrable functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, not a single function whose values at individual points would carry any meaning - all that matters is what happens when you integrate it over regions of non-zero measure, and that information is recoverable from the density matrix.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer (esp. the part about associated spectral projector - what is it?), but the conclusion seems odd. Let's take an EPR-like state as an example. Do you mean that Alice is able to reconstruct the wave function of the whole system (Alice + Bob) just from her measurements and compute correlations between her and Bob's spin projections, etc?

Comment: @xaxa No, because Alice can effectively only perform measurements on her part of the system, i.e. the reduced density matrix obtained by the partial trace over Bob's state space, and there is no wavefunction for that reduced matrix because the original state was entangled, see also [this answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192372/50583). Note that my answer starts with the stipulation that you know that your matrix corresponds to a pure state.

Comment: I should probably update my question, because by $\rho_S$ I meant the reduced density matrix - partial trace over other subsystem's variables.

Comment: @xaxa Oops, I completely overlooked that your question is about $\rho_S$! But, then I'm not sure what the question is - since the $\rho_S$ lives only on the space of (say, Alice), you can't compute expectation values of operators that act non-trivially on Bob's space at all, so it's directly obvious there's information in $\rho$ that's not in $\rho_S$.

Comment: The question is that if I'm only interested in Alice's observables, don't care about Bob's space, is there something I'm not able to calculate with $\rho_S$ that would otherwise be able to calculate if I knew $\left|\Psi\right>$?

Comment: @xaxa No, that's the whole point of the reduced density matrix. But you cannot construct a wavefunction for $S$ because $\rho_S$ is a mixed, not a pure, state and therefore has no wavefunction. I have edited my answer.

Comment: But is there a difference then to Alice, I mean "observation-wise", between a pure state and a mixed state? If Alice sees an incoming photon she should by default consider it to be in a mixed state. It is only _after_ she receives a call from Bob that she can find out whether their mutual state is separable or not. Is this correct? But then again there may appear to be Charlie, entangled with them, and what Alice and Bob thought to a pure state turns out to be a mixed one. So the concept of "purity" seems to bite its own tail, is it not?

Comment: Your description of reconstruction of the wavefunction of a pure state completely misses information about phase.

Comment: @xaxa Note that you cannot "observe" $\rho$ - you can perhaps figure it out after several measurements on identically prepared states, but when you get a quantum system in a state (pure *or* mixed), you generically *don't know* its wavefunction/density matrix. There is a clear criterion on the level of the density matrix for whether it is a pure or mixed state.: A pure state has $\rho^2 = \rho$, so the notion is well-defined. You should perhaps revise the fundamentals of the density matrix formalism.

Comment: Yes, I implied that there exists an apparatus that periodically emits photons in the same state... Anyway, the measuring of $\rho$ solves my confusion. Indeed, if there is enough number of observables, it seems to be "doable". At least for $1/2$-spin (if I didn't miscalculate) $\bar{s_x}^2+\bar{s_y}^2+\bar{s_z}^2 = 1/2$ for a pure state, otherwise it's $<1/2$. Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

> So, *if I limit myself to S* what is it that I cannot calculate using $\mathbf{\rho}_S$ that I'd be able to calculate if I knew $\left|\Psi\right>$?

Locally to $S$? Nothing. As you've noted, the partial trace to $S$ gives you complete information about all local measurements.

> It seems such things should exist, otherwise I'd be able to construct the wave function for S (is that correct?)

The problem here is that there might not *be* such a thing as a "wavefunction for $S$": even if the multipartite system is in a pure state $|\Psi\rangle$, if the state is entangled then there are states (and measurements on those states) that cannot be described by *any* wavefunction on the $S$ Hilbert space.

For an easy example, consider two entangled qubits on the Bell triplet state
$$
\left|\Psi\right\rangle = \frac{|0\rangle|0\rangle+|1\rangle|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
along with the local obervables $A_i=\sigma_i$, the Pauli matrices. Then the partial trace to the first qubit gives you the reduced density matrix
$$
\rho_s = \frac{|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle1|}{2},
$$
which has zero expectation value for all three $A_i$s, which is impossible for a pure state. If you *can* describe $\rho_s$ in the form $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, then by all means go for it, but in general this is not possible.